# c# Programme Error

Tags: c#

Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\FootballLeague.exe" to "bin\Debug\FootballLeague.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\FootballLeague.exe' because it is being used by another process.

I got this problem and I couldnt find any another process.Other c# programmes are working properly.I changed the place which I haved saved first time, but I couldnt get any clue to find the error.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are the other process *is* FootballLeague.exe - are you sure you aren't still running it?

Another alternative is to use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find out what's got a handle on the file.

Comment: I used Process Explorer to find the file which is used the same file like FootballLeague.exe and I deleted every FootballLeague.exe files and every previous folders of this programme, but still I received this message and I couldnt execute my programme.

Comment: I sorted out the problem, but when I try it every time I need to delete the old exe file from process explorer and then I can execute the programme.
Also I closed all the other Visual Studio projects which I opened.
Can you please give me your opinion about this?
Because this is happened to me first time, I have done over 15 projects using visaul studio c#.

Comment: @Kumu: No idea, I'm afraid - sounds odd to me.

Answer (score 0):

If your `FootballLeague.exe` has been launched and is still running, *it* is the process that is locking the file.

Comment: Thank you these answers finally working for my system and I edited my exit button from (this.Close) to  (Application.Exit) then this system is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a virus scanner turned on? They tend to open files for exclusive access at *just* the wrong time. I would advise that you turn off real-time scanning in your project directory at a minimum.

Other than that, you'll want to use something like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find out who *actually* has the file open.